# How to calculate average based on condition in excel using vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a sheet("DATA"), where I have a table with 3 columns and 162 datasets (rows) + the header. That's how the table looks like:

[image]

I need to calculate average of the column C ("Training Status [%]"), based on the site name in the column A ("Site").

I made a macro that creates a table in a new sheet ("Overview"), where each site is stated only once, and now I have to calculate average of "Training Status" for each site.

Final table:

[image]

How could I get the right values into the final table based on the data from the original table, plus consider the condition that the average has to be calculated for each site name? Of course, there is not the same amount of datasets for each site (e.g. "BRU-Logistics" has 3 datasets and "FRA-Logistics" has 15 datasets).

I found some vba codes, but honestly I really did not understand the logic behind and was not able to pass it to my need.

Well, my code is not complete. I just tried to start somehow, but I got lost.

```
Sub Average()

Dim rng As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim r1 As Long, r2 As Long
Dim lNoRows As Long

LastRow = Sheets("DATA").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Set rng = Sheets("DATA").Range("A2:C" & LastRow)
lNoRows = rng.Row.Count

For r1 = 1 To lNoRows
 If rng(r1, 1) = rng(r2, 1) And r1 = r2 Then

End Sub
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Use AVERAGEIF()

Comment: Please share your code, so that we can help you identify the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need VBA for this. In cell D2, put `=AVERAGEIF(A:A,A2,C:C)` , then copy down.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I also tried this solution, but it is not cosidering the name of the site. I mean, when I change sorting in the final table, then the values do not match with the right site name.  Probably it would work when combining vlookup.

Comment: Post a screenshot? AVERAGEIF should definitely work.